# Local variables inside R function doesn't work

Tags: r, function, local-variables

I need your help. I have a data frame looks like below

```
   id      home_1     home_2      home_3
1   1 -0.07288651 -1.0946734  0.06310788
2   2  0.27480575 -0.5939264 -0.10267407
3   3 -1.29267610 -1.0765848 -0.96190129
4   4 -0.53468273  0.5315489 -1.36055340
...
```

I want to create 3 data frames; **df1**, **df2** and **df3**

- **df1** would have a table with *sorted* column 'home_1'
- **df2** would have a table with *sorted* column 'home_2'
- **df3** would have a table with *sorted* column 'home_3'

---

Please find the codes below

```
dummy <- data.frame(id = 1:10,home_1 = rnorm(10),home_2 = rnorm(10),home_3 = rnorm(10))

f <- function(df,param1, param2) {
    c <- paste0(param1, "_", param2);
    print(paste0("Let's sort column ", c))
    df %>% arrange(c) %>% print()  #sort dataframe by column 'home_1/2/3'
}

for (i in 1:3) {
    print(paste0("Index : ",i))
    table <- paste0("df",i)     
    table <- f(dummy,"home",i) # create dataframe with name df1/2/3
}
```

---

**Problem 1**
Then I run my code, the function cannot detect the respective column. The errors inside my function

```
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
Column `c` is unknown
```

the local variable **c** does exist, but the **group_by** function cannot detect **c**.

> Does anybody know how to make **Column 'c'** to be detected by group_by function?

**Problem 2**
Same problem with my for loop. I want to create a data frame name that is dynamic.

> However, this following function **table <- f(dummy,"home",i)**, created a data frame with name **'table'** instead of **'df1'**.

Can anybody give me a hint on how to resolve these issues? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df1<- df[order(df$home_1),] df2<- df[order(df$home_2),]  df3<- df[order(df$home_3),]` As I suppose, solution such like this won't satisfy you, will it?

Comment: @Adamm No sir, I want the function to be dynamic. Because I am going to create more than 50+ data frames with the function.

Comment: Ahh sure, so solution by chinsoon12 should do the trick, unless you want each df (sorted already) in separate variable. Afther that `lapply()` you have list of df's. However you can acces each row and column of df in list by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use tidyverse's arrange function for this, which is very straight forward.

I'd also use "assign" from base-r to assign a value to a vetor who's name is stored in a string.

```
library(tidyverse)
for(i in 1:(ncol(dummy)-1)){
  #define the name for the new data
  new = paste0("df",i) 

  #define the same of the column to sort on
  col = paste("home",i,sep="_") 

  # based on the data dummy, arrange the rows according to "col"
  # we need to use "get" because arrange expects bare (unquoted) column names
  tmp = dummy %>% arrange(get(col))
  assign(new, tmp)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the list of columns and then order by each column

```
cols <- structure(setdiff(names(dat), "id"), names=setdiff(names(dat), "id"))
lapply(cols, function(x) dat[order(dat[,x]),])
```

data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="id      home_1     home_2      home_3
1 -0.07288651 -1.0946734  0.06310788
2  0.27480575 -0.5939264 -0.10267407
3 -1.29267610 -1.0765848 -0.96190129
4 -0.53468273  0.5315489 -1.36055340", header=TRUE)
```